# System.nanoTime how consistently accurate should it be? - Java

Tags: java, time, timer, system

I am speed testing a function for creating a maze and my total time to run I am returning is varying every time. From around:

0.004692336s to 0.01715823s

Just wondering if this is normal or a little odd as I have never used the system timer before. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29

Comment: Thanks seems like it is fairly normal but still hard to tell on the accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.nanoTime()` [provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()). That means you should only use it to measure elapsed time.